# Why is `-p1` to `patch` here?

Tags: git, diff, patch

For revert the changes to a file in a commit, from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2620822/156458

```
#!/bin/bash

function output_help {
    echo "usage: git-revert-single-file <sha1> <file>"
}

sha1=$1
file=$2

if [[ $sha1 ]]; then
git diff $sha1..$sha1^ -- $file | patch -p1
else
output_help
fi
```

Why is `-p1` to `patch` in

```
git diff $sha1..$sha1^ -- $file | patch -p1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Because `git diff` adds fake directories `a` and `b` to its patches, which need to be skipped by `patch` (hence the `-p1`). `git` does this to represent information that’s not in the file system (the files being compared don’t exist simultaneously); for example

```
diff --git a/README b/README
index ce01362..a1e6cf9 100644
--- a/README
+++ b/README
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 hello
+Tim
```

for a README file in the current directory. `diff` would produce

```
--- README.orig 2017-04-07 20:39:50.843962430 +0200
+++ README      2017-04-07 20:39:56.284108455 +0200
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 hello
+Tim
```

(assuming we’ve kept a copy of the original elsewhere); note the absence of directories here (since the files are in the current directory).

The latter patch applies as-is with `patch`; the former needs to have the first element of each path stripped, hence the `-p1`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain in an example? Does `diff` also do the same as `git diff`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610744/can-i-get-a-patch-compatible-output-from-git-diff

Comment: I've added examples.